# Call render from different class in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to seperate my rendering of a class in another class and just call the rendering. Do you know how to do this in React Native? Would be great if you can help me out here.

Thanks a lot

Albo

Comment: I just wanted to seperate rendering and logic. For example you have a class Home which has business logic and rendering for your view. I want to seperate business logic in one class and rendering of your view in another class. Question now clear? Sorry for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

You have to write a Class like this for example:

```
export default class HomeRender extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Text>
              Hi
          </Text>
      </View>
    );
} 
}
module.exports = HomeRender;
```

After that you have simple to do the following in your class to call the render function from HomeRender:

```
var Home = require('./app/components/home/HomeRender');
...
render() {
 <View>
  <Home />
 </View>

}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling render from another class is not good practice. Instead create a new component class and import that class in your view. It will render.

Comment: Do you know how to call functions from another class? For example on button click?

Comment: Create a ES6 class and write your method in that class and in your parent class import the class and make an object of class and call that method from that object

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practise man, in react-native you should always import your component and insert it wherever you want like this:

Import your render file which you want like this:

```
            var Home = require('./app/components/home/HomeRender');
```

Again, wherever yo want to import that component which consists certain view you can render inside your specific like this:

```
render() {
   <View>
       your wish component.... <Home/>
    </View>
  }
```

This will ease your work in navigation part as well as to render your components which return view in wherever you want. Also, you should follow official documentation of react-native as well: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html